# Output not proper when calling batch file programatically

Tags: c#, batch-file, jboss, cmd, wix

I was trying to automate server patch installation for my product and I came to know about Wix Toolset.
I was hoping to get the JBoss Version in my installer. The command to get the same is `standalone.bat --version` from cmd. 
So from my installer I created one CustomAction where I tried to run it and get the output.

```
public static string runRunnableBatch(string path){
    Process exploitVersionService = new Process();
    string runnableBinPath = path;
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path + "bin";
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.FileName = path + "bin\\standalone.bat";
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("--version");
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    exploitVersionService.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    exploitVersionService.Start();
    exploitVersionService.WaitForExit();
    // /*
    string opt = "";
    while (!exploitVersionService.StandardOutput.EndOfStream){
        opt += exploitVersionService.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }
    // */
    //using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\_log.txt"))
    //using (StreamReader reader = exploitVersionService.StandardOutput){
    //    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    //    for (; ; ){
    //        string textLine = reader.ReadLine();
    //        if (textLine == null)
    //            break;
    //        writer.WriteLine(textLine);
    //    }
    //}
    //StreamReader exploitVersionFeed = exploitVersionService.StandardOutput;
    //string output = exploitVersionFeed.ReadToEnd();
    return opt;
}
```

When I was doing that, all I got as output was the first line of the whole output string.

I needed the whole string in my code so that from regular expression I could extract the version.

Also tried with

```
public static string runRunnableBatch(string path){
    string executableBinPath = path + "bin";
    string executableBinPath_BatchCmd = "cd " + "\"" + executableBinPath + "\"";
    string outputFileName = "TempVerInfoHolder.txt";
    string outputFilePath = executableBinPath+@"\TempVerInfoHolder1.txt";
    string versionRetriever_BatchCmd = @"standalone.bat --version > " + "\""+outputFilePath+"\"";
    string partitionName_BatchCmd = @Strings.Utils.getPartitionFromPath(path);

    // Creating command sequence
    SortedList<int, string> commandSequence = new SortedList<int, string>();

    // ~ d:
    commandSequence.Add(1, partitionName_BatchCmd);
    // ~ cd %path%
    commandSequence.Add(2, executableBinPath_BatchCmd);
    // ~ standalone.bat --version > %filename%
    commandSequence.Add(3, versionRetriever_BatchCmd);
    runCommandFromSequence(commandSequence);

    // Run together

    return "";
}

private static void runCommandFromSequence(SortedList<int, string> commandSequence){
    Process seqCmdExecHost = new Process();

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = false;

    seqCmdExecHost.StartInfo = psi;
    seqCmdExecHost.Start();

    using (StreamWriter writer = seqCmdExecHost.StandardInput) {
        if (writer.BaseStream.CanWrite) {
            foreach (int item in commandSequence.Keys){
                MessageBox.Show(seqCmdExecHost.Id.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(commandSequence[item]);
                writer.WriteLine(commandSequence[item]);   
            }
        }

        string opt = "";
        while (!seqCmdExecHost.StandardOutput.EndOfStream){
            opt += seqCmdExecHost.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }
    MessageBox.Show("Exited? " + seqCmdExecHost.HasExited);
    MessageBox.Show("O/P? " + opt);
    }
}
```

I have tried some other way as well. Switching the commented code of the above function was one of them.

Output getting while doing it from code level

> Calling "D:\Servers\VA\XYZ\JBoss-7.1.1-Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat

Output while running the same command manually from cmd

> Calling D:\Servers\VA\XYZ\JBoss-7.1.1-Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat
>
> ======================================================================
>   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: D:\Servers\VA\XYZ\JBoss-7.1.1-Final
>
> JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java
>
> JAVA_OPTS
>
> ======================================================================
>   Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
>
> 19:08:08,333 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
>
> JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

My observation is, the stream is getting closed once the nested standalone.conf.bat is getting called from standalone.bat.

If any workaround available to get the full output in string/buffer/stream, would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to Retrieve the entire output from a batch file

Comment: Yes. Entirely. Util the moments JBoss shows the version information and exits the JVM.

Comment: Is there no more direct way to detect the version of JBoss?  A registry value or a EXE / DLL version?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is call the Command line Application instead of calling the batch file

```
exploitVersionService.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path + "bin";
exploitVersionService.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
exploitVersionService.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
exploitVersionService.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /c \"{0}\" --version",path + "bin\\standalone.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around to do achieve this. 
I created the batch file programmatically and ran it with cmd.

```
public static void createBatchToGetVersion(string path)
            {
                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Started creating batch file");
                BatchOps.executableBinPath = path + "bin";
                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Ëxecutable bin path: " + BatchOps.executableBinPath);
                BatchOps.tempBatchFileName = "JBossVerCmd.bat";
                BatchOps.holderFileName = @"JBossVerHolder.txt";
                BatchOps.absoluteHolderPath = Strings.Utils.normalize(executableBinPath) + holderFileName;
                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Normalized absoluteHolderPath: " + BatchOps.absoluteHolderPath);

                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Checking if JBOSS_HOME entered by user actuallty points to JBOSS");
                if (!File.Exists(Strings.Utils.normalize(executableBinPath) + "standalone.bat"))
                {
                    CustomLogger.getInstance().error("standalone.bat not found. JBOSS_HOME Dir is not correctly entered");
                    throw new CustomExceptions.DirectoryNotAcceptableException("Bad directory is assigned to JBOSS_HOME or JBOSS_HOME structure corrupted");
                }

                /*
                 * Batch file formation.
                 * Contains:
                 * Start file
                 * D:
                 * cd D:\Fusion Server\jboss 7.1.1\bin
                 * @echo | call standalone.bat --version > sample.txt   
                 * @echo Done
                 * End file
                 * @echo is required here because it exits the cmd when completed whithout having the user pressing any key
                */
                string changePartition_cmd = Strings.Utils.getPartitionFromPath(path);
                string changeDirectory_cmd = @"cd " + BatchOps.executableBinPath;
                string getVersion_cmd = @"@echo | call standalone.bat --version > " + holderFileName;
                string exitCmd = @"@echo Done";

                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Command to be written on batch file");
                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("\r\n" + changePartition_cmd + "\r\n" + changeDirectory_cmd + "\r\n" + getVersion_cmd + "\r\n" + exitCmd);

                SortedList<int, string> commandSequence = new SortedList<int, string>();
                CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Initializing command sequence.");
                commandSequence.Add(1, changePartition_cmd);
                commandSequence.Add(2, changeDirectory_cmd);
                commandSequence.Add(3, getVersion_cmd);
                commandSequence.Add(4, exitCmd);

                // Will create one if file never existed and open one delete the content and set the pointer to the begnning
                // if already existed
                StreamWriter batchFileWriter = null;
                try
                {
                    CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Establishing stream to and from temp batch file");
                    batchFileWriter = new StreamWriter(tempBatchFileName);
                    CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Command sequence ready to be written on temp batch file.");
                    Perform.writeToStreamFromSequence(batchFileWriter, commandSequence);
                    CustomLogger.getInstance().debug("Command sequence successfully written");
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    CustomLogger.getInstance().error("Error while writing command sequence.\n" + ex.ToString());
                    // throw exception to CustomAction
                    throw new IOException("Error while writing commandSequence");

                }
                finally
                {
                    // Not required. Stream already closed in writeToStreamFromSequence
                }
            }


            public static void runTempBatchFile()
            {
                Process seqCmdExecHost = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/c " + BatchOps.tempBatchFileName);
                procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                seqCmdExecHost.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                seqCmdExecHost.Start();
                seqCmdExecHost.WaitForExit();
                seqCmdExecHost.Close();
            }
```

I found the moment i was doing

```
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute=true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true
```

It was giving the first line of output. Dont know why?. If anyone has any idea about it please explain.

Thanks